# Apache Virtual Host Set up

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to set up virtual hosts on apache2 set up via WAMP. I have set the below code in the vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/inspection/"
    ServerName inspection
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The trouble is when I go to inspection it takes me to  the WAMP document root not the root of the inspection folder like specified in the DocumentRoot section above.

Where am I going wrong above. I also didn't know if it maybe something overriding it in the httpd.conf file. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I uncommented the include line in httpd.conf which I hadn't seen to do before and now it points to the right place but if I attempt to use the submit button which takes me to `http://inspection/confirm.php`. In IE it says Cannot display the page and Chrome says no data was transmitted. If I go back to no vhosts it works fine.

Comment: You realize you misspelled `inspection` in your pasted configuration?

Comment: fixed the spelling but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have:

- a [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) line in your conf somewhere *before* the `<VirtualHost...` block (i.e. directly above it in the same file) and that the server name and port (`*:80`) match
- an entry in the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) for `inspection` so that `http://inspection/` resolves to your localhost (127.0.0.1)
- cleared your browser's cache and cookies
- restarted Apache

Answer (score 0):

Put an actual IP address where you have *:80, and also have a Listen directive for that same IP address.